# Reset Socket input stream in Java

Tags: java, sockets, stream, chat, reset

I am developing chat application in Java, allowing more users to connect to server. I managed to establish communication between clients, but the problem is when client sends message for the first time server recieves it and send it to destination client. But when the same client sends message for second time (and so on) server recieves message it receieved for the first time, so destination client is recieving the same message over and over again... I send object of type Message which I defined in another class..

I googled a little bit, and found out, that the problem is in stream and it should be reseted after each data had gone through stream. Output stream is possible to reset, but it doesent help. When I try to reset input stream I get an error. I runned out of ideas, has anybody got one?

Comment: Show your code. Also if you're using ObjectStreams, it's a bad idea for a chat application.

Comment: i have main class where i accept sockets and another class which i instance for each connection (for each client new thread)

Comment: here is code: http://pastebin.com/7Bap5zHk

what would be a good idea for a chat application instead of ObjectStreams?

Comment: Your own binary or text protocol. ObjectStreams have all that serialization stuff in them, which make them tricky to use if you don't know how serialization works.

Comment: Show the code of the client - probably it sends the first message each time.

Comment: no it doesnt.
http://pastebin.com/4buCn0y2

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to call ObjectOutputStream.reset(). See the Jqvadoc for why.

Comment: Tried it how? You need to call it before resending the same object if it now has different values. You could also investigate `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared().`

Comment: i have tried writing it just after ObjectOutputStream.write(message);

now i changed a type of message from Message to String, and it works..

Comment: does anybody have idea why it doesnt work with objects. My message class looks like this:http://pastebin.com/3uqjuNJi